# можно ли сделать сменяющийся статус без js?

Tags: javascript, css

вот есть js, который позволяет менять строку на какую-то другую строку, а можно достичь таких же успехов на css?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var is_save = false;
        function saveStatus(el)
        {   
            if(is_save) return;
            is_save = true;
            var new_status = el.value;
            el.outerHTML = '<span id="status_text" onclick="changeStatus(this);">' + new_status + '</span>';
            
        }
        function saveStatusEnter(el)
        {
            events = event || window.event;
            ent_press = events.keyCode == 13;
            if(ent_press) saveStatus(el);
        }
        function changeStatus(el)
        {
            var last_status = el.innerHTML;
            el.outerHTML = '<input id="status_text" type="text" value="' + last_status + '" onblur="saveStatus(this)" onkeyup="saveStatusEnter(this);"/>';
            document.getElementById('status_text').focus();
            is_save = false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="status_text" onclick="changeStatus(this);">Last Status</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#status_text {
  border: 1px none;
}
#status_text:focus {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<input id="status_text" value="Last Status" onkeyup="if(event.keyCode == 13)this.blur()"/>
```

Comment: В ваш код в отличии от кода автора вопроса попадаешь по TAB =) Но идея прикольная =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Да, табуляцию я упустил.